# Missing artifact in Maven Project

Tags: maven

I am hitting the error Missing artifact in my maven project. What's going wrong?

Error:

[image: Error]

It is not working only in one of my laptop and the rest are fine. The setup and everything is the same.

Method tried:

1. I have tried to update the maven project where i used to do if i have this dependency issue but this time it failed.
2. I have tried to run the "mvn install" and it shows the error message below:

   > [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Spearhead-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.triaset.spearhead:Spearhead-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.triaset.spearhead:Spearhead-ejb:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.triaset.spearhead:Spearhead-ejb:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.triaset.spearhead:Spearhead-ejb:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT from/to prime-repo (https://repository.primefaces.org): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

Comment: you can copy the repo to your new laptop then change the repo path from maven setting.xml if its not working please post more details

Comment: Please don't make links to images...better paste the error text into the posting...Apart from that You have defined a dependency to an ejb packaging but you have not defined the `<type>ejb</type>` ...